# What is the "iPhone viewport scale bug"?

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari, html5boilerplate

[HTML5 mobile boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) recommends adding this snippet of Javascript to fix the "iPhone viewport scale bug":

```
// Fix for iPhone viewport scale bug 
// http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

MBP.viewportmeta = document.querySelector && document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
MBP.ua = navigator.userAgent;

MBP.scaleFix = function () {
  if (MBP.viewportmeta && /iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(MBP.ua) && !/Opera Mini/.test(MBP.ua)) {
    MBP.viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0";
    document.addEventListener("gesturestart", MBP.gestureStart, false);
  }
};
MBP.gestureStart = function () {
    MBP.viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6";
};
```

- What is the "iPhone viewport scale bug"? (The linked blog post doesn't make sense to me)
- How does this code go about fixing the bug? (I.e., what exactly does it do?)

Answer (score 3):

View this [demo page](https://webdesignerwall.com/demo/iphone-scaling-bug/scaling-bug.html) with an iPhone. Rotate the phone from portrait to landscape. Notice the page being scaled up on landscape view.

See here to know in Detail http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug

check comments too.

This screenshot should help too:
[image]
<sub>(source: [webdesignerwall.com](http://webdesignerwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/iphone-viewport-scaling-bug.png))</sub>